# (plural noun) "are" never "a" good idea.

Tags: grammar, nouns, verb-agreement

I'd like to know how to explain the grammar in this kind of sentences. It seems to me that the plural noun here works like a collective noun... Or does it purely depend on the context rather than some grammatical rules? Thank you.

For example: (A random quote from an online article)
"While we can't confirm the footage mix-up, these kinds of accusations **are** never **a** good thing."

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable question and is not off-topic. It's a legitimate question about English grammar, and anyone who thinks it's off-topic should try answering it before they close it. It's not a simple matter.

Answer (score 5):

> These kinds of accusations *are* never *a* good thing

Here, in the above sentence,

*Are* is used in association with *accusations*. (accusations = more than 1 accusation)

Whereas, *A* is used in association with *good thing*. (not good *things* but *thing*)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm fully aware what you are saying here and I know the sentence is correct but I just feel I don't complete get it in terms of grammar. 

Why didn't they write "These kinds of accusations are never good thingS" instead?

Comment: @Eliza They used *good thing* as a collective phrase directed towards many accusations

Comment: Now I see. I assume the same principle also applies to "a good idea" then?

Comment: @Eliza Naturally, like you may say "Their idea was too good to turn down*, here idea refers to all those who suggested it.

Comment: More importantly, _a good thing_ is the predicate (_are_ is the auxiliary verb for a predicate noun). Predicates do not agree with subjects in person and number -- **auxiliary verbs** agree with subjects in person and number. So the choice between _is_ and _are_ depends entirely on the subject _kinds_, which is plural; the number of the predicate noun has nothing to do with the auxiliary verb.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thank you for your explanation. It's very clear.